# I'm getting undefined when i'm getting the button id in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have this code working fine in Chrome, Firefox on pc and android devices but it does not work in macbook with safari or Iphone with sarafi or Chrome. I'm getting undefined at the variable grupo. So I'm sending "undefined" in the Ajax request.

**Context:** I have a group of buttons created on document.ready with an id. And I have a function to know the id of the clicked button, and send that ID with an Ajax post request and I'm getting undefined as response.

This code work well in every web navigator. Just for context.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //testing Jquery
  //console.log("esta funcionando Jquery");

  var basicProfile = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const email = basicProfile.get("e");
    const imagen = basicProfile.get("imageURL");
    var idFechaAgenda;

    generarGrupos();

function generarGrupos() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'php-grupos.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {email},
      success: function(response) {
        grupos = JSON.parse(response);
        document.getElementById('profilePicture').src = imagen;
        document.getElementById('lblNombre').innerText = grupos[0].nombreDocente;
        document.getElementById('lblCorreo').innerText = email;
        let template = '';
        var cont = 0;
        grupos.forEach(response => {
          template += ` // This work fine in every web navigator
                  <tr taskId="${grupos[cont].idDocente}">
                    <td style="display:none">${grupos[cont].idDocente}</td>
                    <td class="text-center align-middle fw-bold">${grupos[cont].grupoDocente}</td>
                    <td id="resultado${grupos[cont].idDocente}">
                      <button type="button" id="${grupos[cont].grupoDocente}" class="btn-verAlumnos btn-primary bg-dark w-100 fw-bold">Ver alumnos</button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                `       
                cont++;
        });
        $('#tableFechas').html(template);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error){
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }
```

With this code, I'm getting var grupo = undefined with `console.log` only in MacOS using Safari or Iphone using Safari and Chrome. With another devices works fine.

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-verAlumnos', (e) =>{
    const element = $(this)[0].activeElement;
    var grupo = $(element).attr('id'); // i think this is the problem :(
    $.ajax({
      url: 'php-listaAlumnos.php',
      data: {grupo},
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(response){
        let alumnos = JSON.parse(response);
        let table = '';
        var cont = 0;
        alumnos.forEach(alumno => {
          table += `
            <tr AlumnoId="${alumnos[cont].num}">
              <td class="text-center align-middle fw-bold">${alumnos[cont].num}</td>
              <td id="Alumno${alumnos[cont].num}" class="text-center align-middle fw-bold">${alumnos[cont].matricula}</td>
              <td class="text-center align-middle fw-bold">${alumnos[cont].nombre}</td>
            </tr>
          `
          cont++;
        });
        $('#tableAlumnos').html(table);
        $('#alumnosModal').modal('show');
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error){
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
```

Question: There is another way to get the id of the clicked button and sent it with the post request without getting undefined at group variable? (I think this is the problem).

Comment: `$(this)[0]` is `window`. There's no `window.activeElement` property, it should be `document.activeElement`.

Comment: The clicked button is `e.currentTarget`, so I think you want `var grupo = e.currentTarget.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `e.target` instead of `this` for the `click` event.

You're also using some unnecessary properties and selectors to get the appropriate element such as `[0]` and `.activeElement`. Explanation: in the `click` event there will always only be 1 element rendering the `[0]` selector useless. Also, the `.activeElement` property returns which element has focus. You've already determined which `.btn-verAlumnos` was clicked in the `click` event.

Please also mind that there's no need to wrap the element as a jQuery element twice.

Taken this explanation into consideration try the following code:

```
// Instead of:
const element = $(this)[0].activeElement;
var grupo = $(element).attr('id');

// Use this:
const element = $(e.target);
var grupo = element.attr('id');
```

Comment: i tried it and it worked without problem. Thank you. Also i found this way and it works too. var grupo = event.srcElement.id;

Comment: @Fuss great! If you found that this answer worked for you please consider marking it as an accepted answer.